# How to create dynamic input fields in html

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I want to dynamically create multiple dropbox fields as I input the number of fields to be created.

For instance, there are 2 fields:

1. integer input field
2. dropdown menu

so when I input(let's say "4" in field 1) then 4 dropdowns should be created.

[image]

How should it be done? And upon submitting the form the same will be stored as a list in a database (flask is used at the backend).

Please guide.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask is rather lightweight framework so to create fields dynamically use Javascript. Note nowadays its preferred to develop websites using some advanced JS library or 'framework' JQuery, vue, react etc. On backend you create a controller to save the data. Start with going though a tutorial to understand the procedure. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6N4OmsfwfdU . If you use WTF find a tutorial or discussion specific to WTF.